# How to "GET" request from JSON objects passed through HTML form

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I'd like to submit my input fields to an json object and pass it to the HTML table list. I've looked over similar StackOverflow solutions but nothing works. ***I am able to send my input fields to a JSON object, but I cannot "GET" request it to show up as HTML page text.***

How can I "GET" request the json object passed through my HTML form?

### [This is what the solution should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLDn3.png)

### [This is what the page currently shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HlXP.png)

#### main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, render_template_string, jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

headings = ["Name", "Channel", "Bots", "Status"]

@app.route("/")
def home():
    content = "data.js"
    return render_template("botList.html", headings=headings)


@app.route("/list", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def list():
    username = request.form["username"]
    channel = request.form["channel"]
    bots = request.form["bots"]
    status = request.form["status"]
    return render_template("botList.html", headings=headings,
                                            data=tableData,
                                            username=username,
                                            channel=channel,
                                            bots=bots,
                                            status=status)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> You can see in ***main.py*** I tried passing the form inputs but... no luck.

#### botList.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        {% for header in headings %}
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for row in listData %}
        <tr>
            {% for cell in row %}
            <td>{{ cell }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>

<form method="POST" action="/list">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="ex. janedoe"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="channel">Channel</label>
        <input type="text" name="channel" id="channel" placeholder="ex. TikTok US"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="bots">Bots</label>
        <input type="text" name="bots" id="bots" placeholder="ex. 1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Status">Status</label>
        <input type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Offline" value="Offline"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="btn">Click to Add Bot</button>
    </div>
    <div id="msg">
        <pre></pre>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    let listData = [];

    const addBot = (ev)=>{
        ev.preventDefault();  //to stop the form submitting
        let bot = {
            username: document.getElementById('username').value,
            channel: document.getElementById('channel').value,
            bots: document.getElementById('bots').value,
            status: document.getElementById('status').value
        }
        listData.push(bot);
        document.forms[0].reset(); // to clear the form for the next entries
        //document.querySelector('form').reset();

        //for display purposes only
        console.warn('added' , {listData} );
        let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
        pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(listData, '\t', 2);

        //saving to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('listData', JSON.stringify(listData) );
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addBot);
        return listData
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

#### base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Program</title>
        <!-- INCLUDING JQUERY-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you intend to do on the client side and what you intend to do on the server side. At the moment these cannot be separated from each other. You save data on the client side. Due to the type of button used, the form data should never be sent to the server. However, there is a request for the form data on the server. There is no distinction on the server between GET and POST. If so, how would you like to save the data on the server? To summarize, which technology would you like to use for what?

Comment: @Detlef to be honest, I'm not really sure. How do I send the data to the server?

Comment: OK. I advise you to do [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) about flask. If you add an attribute "type" with the value "submit" to the button, the data will be sent to the server. Your javascript code will then no longer work. Am I correct in assuming that you actually want to save the data on the server?

Comment: @Detlef Yeah I would like to save the data in some storage database so I can access it later in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small example that is essentially what you tried. Nevertheless, I advise you to read [this flask tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). There are a lot of good examples of developing with the flask framework. Please look around a little.
I can't explain all the details and this is the wrong place for that.

In the following example, for reasons of practicality, I make do with a few practices that are normally not common and should be avoided.
Please familiarize yourself with the use of databases or other types of storage to replace the global variables.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from flask import request 

# As an exception, since I cannot explain the use of a database to you in this 
# example, I use a global variable. You shouldn't actually do this, but it is 
# helpful in this case for the reason described above.
botlist = []

# For the same reason, I use a dataclass to map a model, which is later saved 
# within the defined list.
@dataclass
class Bot:
    username: str
    channel: str
    name: str
    status: str

@app.route('/bots', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bots():
    global botlist
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # If it is a POST request, create a bot object and append it to the list.
        bot = Bot(
            request.form['username'], 
            request.form['channel'], 
            request.form['name'], 
            request.form['status'], 
        )
        botlist.append(bot)

    # Re-render the page with the bots in the list.
    return render_template('bots.html', botlist=botlist)
```

Basically, it should be noted that a jinja2 template is rendered on the server and then sent to the client. However, the contained javascript code is executed on the client.
For the sake of simplicity, I don't use Javascript in this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bots</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="channel">Channel</label>
        <input type="text" name="channel" id="channel"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="status">Status</label>
        <input type="text" name="status" id="status"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Add Bot</button>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Channel</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for bot in botlist -%}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ bot.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ bot.channel }}</td>
          <td>{{ bot.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ bot.status }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor -%}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you that worked! I want to refresh the page and still have the data, how can I save the data in local storage/database and not global variables?

Comment: @mattwelter Use [flask_sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/) and create a model then create the table and from this point you can save and query entries in the database.